# Anonymous edit status unclear; can edits be claimed?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I followed a link to the Chemistry Stack Exchange and suggested edits of [an answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62019). I didn't realize I wasn't a member and was editing anonymously.

First, could the edit form be made clearer that the editor isn't logged in? It does say it at the top of the page but not near the edit box and it's in plain text, so it's easy to miss. Maybe put it in the right column above the "How To Edit" box.

Second, is there a process for someone to claim their edits if they wanted to? It's probably impractical since the anonymous edit is anonymous, but just curious more than anything else (I don't need attribution).

Comment: "is there a process for someone to claim their edits if they wanted to?" - no, there isn't such process.

Comment: What you have here are two separate feature requests. Please either split it into two different questions, or choose one request and focus on it, then remove the non relevant part. IMO better stick with the "edit form be made clearer that the editor isn't logged in" request which is much more feasible. Then you can add the feature request tag back.

Answer (score 3):

*1. Could the edit form be made clearer that the editor isn't logged in?*

When not signed in, you'll see "improve this question" in place of the usual "edit" option. That's one way to notice the difference.

*2. Is there a process for someone to claim their edits if they wanted to?*

Currently, I think not.